# ¿Cómo funcionan "key" y "lambda" en las funciones "max()" o "min()"?

Tags: python, lambda

Me gustaría entender cuál es el funcionamiento y la creación de "keys" o "lambdas" que puedan condicionar a las funciones `max()` o `min()`, aplicadas sobre listas, diccionarios o tuplas.

---

Un ejemplo sobre lo que me refiero sería:

```
def pais_mas_bienes(registros, tipo_bien='Cultural'):
    ''' Calcula el país con mayor número de bienes de un tipo dado
        Devuelve una tupla con el número de bienes y el nombre del país
        
        ENTRADA:
        - registros: lista de tuplas con información de bienes -> [(id, name, year, category, country)]
        - tipo_bien: el tipo de bienes para el que se realizará la operación -> str
        
        SALIDA:
        - Tupla con el número de bienes y el nombre del país -> (int, str)
    '''
    tuplas = list(indexa_por_paises(registros, tipo_bien).items())
    filtro = max(tuplas, key = lambda x: len(x[1]))
    contador = filtra_por_pais_bienes(registros, filtro[0], tipo_bien)
    result = (contador, filtro[0])
    return result
```

Y las funciones auxiliares usadas:

```
def indexa_por_paises(registros, tipo_bien):
    result = {}
    for i in registros:
        if i[3] == tipo_bien and i[4] in result:
            result[i[4]] += [i]
        if i[3] == tipo_bien and i[4] not in result:
            result[i[4]] = [i]
    return result

def filtra_por_pais_bienes(registros, pais, tipo_bien):
    result = [i for i in registros if i[3]==tipo_bien and i[4]==pais]
    return len(result)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las funciones `max()` y `min()`, así como la función `sorted()` necesitan saber cómo comparar dos valores, para determinar en qué orden ponerlos y por tanto cuál es el máximo o el mínimo.

Por defecto Python ya tiene formas de comparar los tipos básicos (entero, cadena, tupla, etc.) Para tus propios tipos (clases) la clase puede incorporar un método `.__lt__()` que se evalúa para hacer la comparación `<`, y si es el caso de que la clase incorpora esos métodos, `sorted()`, `max()` y `min()` los usarán para su ordenación.

Para el caso en que quieras alterar las reglas por defecto de python (o las que incorpore la clase en su método `.__lt__()`, puedes proporcionar un parámetro llamado `key` a estas funciones.

Ese parámetro es el nombre de otra función que debes programar aparte, o bien de una `lambda` si la función es tan simple que consiste meramente en retornar una expresión. Ya sea una función o una `lambda` su funcionamiento es el mismo:

- Recibe un parámetro que es un elemento de la lista que estás ordenando
- Retorna un valor que puede ser entero, cadena, tupla, o alguno de los tipos que python ya sabe ordenar. Ese valor representa el "valor de ordenación" de ese elemento.

Python va llamando a tu función `key` para cada elemento de la lista que quiere ordenar, y lo ordena según el valor retornado por la `key`. Es como si hubiera transformado todos los elementos de tu lista en otros (los que retorne `key`), ordenado esos otros, y después sustituido cada uno por su valor original.

### Un ejemplo (lista de tuplas)

Imagina que tus elementos son tuplas. Por defecto python ya sabe cómo ordenarlas y su método es ordenar según el valor del primer elemento de la tupla, y si son iguales por el segundo, etc. Así:

```
mis_datos = [(1,20), (5,3), (3,1), (2, 10)]
print("Ordenada: ", sorted(mis_datos))
print("Maximo: ", max(mis_datos))
```

```
Ordenada:  [(1, 20), (2, 10), (3, 1), (5, 3)]
Maximo:  (5, 3)
```

Pero resulta que queremos que lo ordene *por el segundo elemento*. Necesitamos entonces hacer una función que recibirá cada tupla y retornará el segundo elemento, por ejemplo así:

```
def get_segundo_elemento(tupla):
    return tupla[1]
```

Usando esta función como `key`:

```
print("Ordenada: ", sorted(mis_datos, key=get_segundo_elemento))
print("Maximo: ", max(mis_datos, key=get_segundo_elemento))
```

```
Ordenada:  [(3, 1), (5, 3), (2, 10), (1, 20)]
Maximo:  (1, 20)
```

En este caso la función es muy simple, en otros casos podría contener dentro condicionales, bucles o lo que necesitaras para computar un "valor de ordenación". En casos tan simple como estos puede que no merezca la pena definir una función e inventar un nombre para ella, sobre todo si no la vas a usar en ningún otro sitio. Puedes usar una expresión lambda en su lugar:

```
print("Ordenada: ", sorted(mis_datos, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Es más, para este caso particular ni siquiera necesitas escribir la función, pues se trata de un caso tan habitual que python ya proporciona funciones para ello en su módulo `operator`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
print("Ordenada: ", sorted(mis_datos, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Aquí la sintaxis puede ser más confusa, pues `itemgetter(1)` es una función que al ejecutarse, te retorna *otra función*, que espera como parámetro una lista o tupla, y te retornará su elemento de índice 1. Personalmente encuentro más clara la expresión *lambda*, pero es conveniente conocer la existencia de las posibilidades que te brinda `operator` para la programación funcional.

#### Otro ejemplo (lista de diccionarios)

Para comparar diccionarios python no tiene método por defecto, por lo que en este caso sí que es imprescindible darle una `key`. E caso más típico suele ser querer ordenar la lista por un campo particular del diccionario. El mecanismo es similar al visto para la tupla. Por ejemplo:

```
mis_datos = [
    { "nombre": "Juan", "edad": 40},
    { "nombre": "Arturo", "edad": 49 },
    { "nombre": "Javier", "edad": 61 },
    { "nombre": "Rodrigo", "edad": 45 }]

sorted(mis_datos, key=lambda x: x["nombre"])
sorted(mis_datos, key=lambda x: x["edad"])
```

O si prefieres:

```
sorted(mis_datos, key=itemgetter("nombre"))
sorted(mis_datos, key=itemgetter("edad"))
```

Fíjate no obstante que se presupone que todos los elementos de la lista son diccionarios que tienen la clave en cuestión.

Si tienes dudas particulares de cómo definir una función `key` para tu lista particular, pregunta de nuevo dando datos de cómo son los elementos de la lista y qué ordenación querrías para ellos.