# ¿Cómo ordenar por orden alfabetico una lista multidimensional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo un archivo de texto que contiene 40 líneas de texto, cada una tiene un nombre, una calificacion y un grupo. Metí todo eso en una lista. por ejemplo:

```
Alumnos = [["gerardo", 5.6, "GrupoA"],["Miguel" , 9.6 , "Grupo B"],["Arturo" , 8.3, "Grupo C"...]]
```

Creé una clase llamada "Alumno" la cual pide 3 parámetros, que son el nombre, calificación y grupo del alumno.

Tengo esto:

```
Class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, nombre, promedio, grupo)
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.promedio = promedio
    self.grupo = grupo 
with open("alumnos.txt", "r") as f:
listaNombres = []
for line in  f:
line = line.rstrip("\\n")
info = line.split()
Estudiante = Alumno(str(info[0], str(info[1]), str(info[2])
Estudiante.nombre = str(info[0])
Estudiante.promedio = str(info[1])
Estudiante.grupo = str(info[2])
listaNombres.append(Estudiante)
```

Con esto puedo acceder al archivo, quitar el salto de línea y dividir cada una de las líneas en una lista individual, así que tengo una lista con listas dentro de ella que son todos los alumnos.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder tomar el nombre de cada estudiante? Así como también poder ordenarlos y que devuelva la lista con todos los parámetros de cada alumno, pero que ahora estén ordenados en orden alfabético.

Comment: Tienes que usar `sort()` con la `key` adecuada. Mira esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216589/7123

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 opciones: usar la función `sorted` que te da como resultado una nueva lista con los valores ordenados o utilizar la función `sort` que opera directamente sobre la lista y la actualiza con el nuevo orden:

```
sorted(alumnosLista, key=lambda x: x[0]) # Genera una nueva lista.

alumnosLista.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) # Actualiza la lista `alumnosLista`.
```

El parámetro `key` indica el valor que usaremos para realizar la ordenación que en este caso será el nombre, que está ubicado la primera posición (index 0) de cada lista interna (para acceder a las listas internas usamos `lambda`).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Aunque parece que los objetos de una clase no soportan el indexing.  Me sale este un TypeError: y dice:" 'Alumno' (El cual es el nombre de mi clase) object does not support indexing.

Comment: Tienes razón, me confundí al ver el primer ejemplo donde señalas que la variable `Alumnos` es igual a la lista que indicas. Donde dice `Alumnos` en el ejemplo que he colocado va la variable que contiene la lista bidimensional.