# Que articulo se vendieron menos en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de tuplas:

```
Tupper 11.4*5.6 cm, 2000, 30, 1400
```

Me pide que muestre cuales son los articulos que se vendieron en menos cantidades. (la fila 3, es la que indica las cantidades vendidas)

No se como seguir la idea, pienso que seria con una condicion if pero no sabria como hacerlo.

Comment: Ya tienes un for que recorre cada fila. ahora solo tienes que ir guardando la tupla `nombre -> cantidad`, luego haces un `sort`(ordenacion ) y sacas el nombre del producto con más ventas.

Comment: Tambien puedes, comprobar en cada iteracion si el valor actual de vendido es el mayor. ej: 1,2,1,3. En la primera iteracion guardas el uno, luego en la segunda guardas el 2 porque es mayor, pero luego en la tercera no guardas el 1 porque es menor que el actualmente guardado 2, y luego gaurdas el 3 quedando asi al acabar el for el producto con más ventas

Comment: @Aylen Mirate [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216589/7123) sobre el uso del parámetro `key` en `sorted()`, para ordenar por un cierto campo de una tupla u otras posibilidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ordenar tu lista en base a una key con [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), luego tomar el primer o último elemento (depende si buscas el de menor o mayor ventas):

```
lista= [] 

archivo= open("arch.txt", "r")

for linea in archivo:

            denominacion, stock, precio, cant_vend = linea.split(",")

            tupla = (denominacion, int(stock), int(precio), int(cant_vend))

            lista.append(tupla)

newList = sorted(lista,key=lambda x: x[3]) //Ordena la lista en forma ascendente tomando como key el valor de la cuarta columna
print(newList)
print(newList[0]) //El primer elemento (menor venta)
print(newList[-1]) //El último elemento (mayor venta)
```

Salida:

```
[('Tupper 14*6.9 cm', 2000, 50, 1100), ('Tupper 16.7*8.1 cm', 2000, 70, 1300), ('Tupper 11.4*5.6 cm', 2000, 30, 1400), ('Mesa', 3000, 700, 1500), ('Silla', 4000, 300, 2000), ('Platos', 4000, 20, 2200), ('Vasos', 3000, 15, 2800), ('Botella', 5000, 100, 3000)]
('Tupper 14*6.9 cm', 2000, 50, 1100)
('Botella', 5000, 100, 3000)
```